# Abp.AbpException: There is no tenant with given id: 2

Tags: mysql, aspnetboilerplate

Got error when start up the template project: 
`Abp.AbpException`:

> There is no tenant with given id: 2

I have checked the DB, there is default tenant and users be created. But failed to load Swagger with error:

> Fetch errorInternal Server Error http://localhost:21021/swagger/v1/swagger.json.

**Checked the txt log and following are the error stack, and I'm confusing where is the tenant id 2 be passed.**

> ERROR 2019-01-09 14:54:25,221 [7    ] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel      - Connection id "0HLJLVT04BST8", Request id "0HLJLVT04BST8:00000003": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   Abp.AbpException: There is no tenant with given id: 2
>      at Abp.MultiTenancy.TenantCache`2.Get(Int32 tenantId) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.Zero.Common\MultiTenancy\TenantCache.cs:line 35
>      at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.TenantCache`2_Get.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
>      at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>      at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
>      at Castle.Proxies.TenantCache`2Proxy.Get(Int32 tenantId)
>      at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver.GetNameOrConnectionString(DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolveArgs args) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\Zero\EntityFrameworkCore\DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver.cs:line 50
>      at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver.GetNameOrConnectionString(ConnectionStringResolveArgs args) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\Zero\EntityFrameworkCore\DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver.cs:line 45
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.GetOrCreateDbContext[TDbContext](Nullable`1 multiTenancySide, String name) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 107
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.get_Table() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Repositories\EfCoreRepositoryBaseOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs:line 39
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetAllIncluding(Expression`1[] propertySelectors) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Repositories\EfCoreRepositoryBaseOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs:line 88
>      at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetAllListAsync(Expression`1 predicate) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Repositories\EfCoreRepositoryBaseOfTEntityAndTPrimaryKey.cs:line 108
>      at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithPostActionAndFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Func`1 postAction, Action`1 finalAction)
>      at Abp.Configuration.SettingStore.GetAllListAsync(Nullable`1 tenantId, Nullable`1 userId) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.Zero.Common\Configuration\SettingStore.cs:line 40
>      at Abp.Threading.InternalAsyncHelper.AwaitTaskWithPostActionAndFinallyAndGetResult[T](Task`1 actualReturnValue, Func`1 postAction, Action`1 finalAction)
>      at Abp.Configuration.SettingManager.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.<<GetUserSettingsFromCache>b__0>d.MoveNext() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Configuration\SettingManager.cs:line 436
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Abp.Runtime.Caching.CacheExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`2.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Abp.Runtime.Caching.CacheBase.GetAsync(String key, Func`2 factory) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Caching\CacheBase.cs:line 182
>      at Abp.Runtime.Caching.CacheExtensions.GetAsync[TKey,TValue](ICache cache, TKey key, Func`2 factory) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Caching\CacheExtensions.cs:line 60
>      at Abp.Configuration.SettingManager.GetUserSettingsFromCache(UserIdentifier user) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Configuration\SettingManager.cs:line 430
>      at Abp.Configuration.SettingManager.GetReadOnlyUserSettings(UserIdentifier user) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Configuration\SettingManager.cs:line 403
>      at Abp.Configuration.SettingManager.GetSettingValueForUserOrNullAsync(UserIdentifier user, String name) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Configuration\SettingManager.cs:line 373
>      at Abp.Configuration.SettingManager.GetSettingValueInternalAsync(String name, Nullable`1 tenantId, Nullable`1 userId, Boolean fallbackToDefault) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Configuration\SettingManager.cs:line 235
>      at Abp.AspNetCore.Localization.AbpUserRequestCultureProvider.DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.AspNetCore\AspNetCore\Localization\AbpUserRequestCultureProvider.cs:line 29
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Abp.AspNetCore.Security.AbpSecurityHeadersMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.AspNetCore\AspNetCore\Security\AbpSecurityHeadersMiddleware.cs:line 26
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
>   INFO  2019-01-09 14:54:25,227 [7    ] soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request finished in 182.7895ms 500

Answer (score 0):

It is browser Swagger cache issue which I authorized swagger yesterday.

It is good ater clear the browser cache. thats why there is a tenant id 2.